# How to expand 2 dimensional dynamic array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I have this code:

```
FILE *fr,*fr2,*fr3; 
fr = fopen("med.txt","r");
fr2 = fopen("moje.txt","w");
fr3 = fopen("zaloha.txt","rw");

int  pRadku, nc, inword, pMezery;
int pSlov = 0;
inword =  0;
pRadku = 1;
inword = 0;  
int radky = 20;
int sloupce = 50;
nc = pMezery = 0;
int pocitadlo = 0;
int pocitadlo2 = 0;
int i,j;
char c;

int tex = 255;

char text; 
for(i= 0; i<tex ;i++){
     text[i]='\0';     
}  

 char **pole;
 int pocet = 1000;
 char *p_pom1, *p_pom2, **p_nove;
 pole = (char **)malloc(pocet * sizeof(char));
 for(i=0; i<pocet; i++){
      pole[i] = (char*)malloc(tex * sizeof(char));    
 }





while(( c=fgetc(fr)) != EOF){


        ++nc;
    if(c == '\n'){
        ++pRadku;
            }
    if(c ==' '){
         pMezery++;
             }
    if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'){
        inword = 0;
    }else if(inword == 0){
            inword = 1;
            ++pSlov;            
    }



  if(pocitadlo >= (pocet-1)){

         int pomPocet = pocet;      
         pocet+=1000;
         pole = (char **)realloc(pole, pocet * sizeof(char));

  }



  if((c != ' ')){
      if(c != '\0'){
           if(c != '\n'){
                if(c != '\t'){
                     if(c != '.'){
                        if(c != ','){
                          text[pocitadlo2]=c;
                          pocitadlo2++;
                        }  
                     }
                }
           }
      }
  }





  if((c == ' ')){
      text[pocitadlo2] = '\0';
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        pole[pocitadlo][i] = text[i];
      }
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        text[i]='\0';
      }
      pocitadlo2=0;
      pocitadlo++;  

  }else if(c == '\0'){
     text[pocitadlo2] = '\0';
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        pole[pocitadlo][i] = text[i];
      }
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        text[i]='\0';
      }
      pocitadlo2=0;
      pocitadlo++;  

  }else if(c == '\n'){
     text[pocitadlo2] = '\0';
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        pole[pocitadlo][i] = text[i];
      }
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        text[i]='\0';
      }
      pocitadlo2=0;
      pocitadlo++;  

  }else if(c == '.'){
      text[pocitadlo2] = '\0';
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        pole[pocitadlo][i] = text[i];
      }
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        text[i]='\0';
      }
      pocitadlo2=0;
      pocitadlo++;  

  }else if(c == ','){
      text[pocitadlo2] = '\0';
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        pole[pocitadlo][i] = text[i];
      }
      for(i=0;i<tex;i++){
        text[i]='\0';
      }
      pocitadlo2=0;
      pocitadlo++;  

  }

}
```

and my question is do I expand my 2 dimensional array properly? Or should do it some different way?

This program read 300 000 words from a file and saving them in to an array.

thx for your time.

EDIT**

```
int row = 5;
int column = 5;
int countr = 0;
int countr2 = 0;

int c;
int **array;

array = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
 for(i=0; i<row; i++){
    pole[i] = (int*)malloc(column * sizeof(int*));    
}

while(read letters form file (c=fgetc()) != EOF{

if(coutr>=(size-1)){
    row+=10;
     array = (int **)realloc(array, row * sizeof(int*));
}

array[countr][countr2] = c;
countr2++;
if(c == '\0' || c == ' '){
    countr2=0;
    countr++;
}
}
```

Comment: What do you meant with "expand" ? If you need to allocate more memory, you could use 'realloc'

Comment: I don't see a 2D array in there, only pointer to pointer which is not the same. Instead of posting a long code like that please boil your problem down to a minimal example.

Comment: Sidenote: please try using english names for your variables. Firstly, it makes the code more readable for people who are not czech, secondly it's kind of standard to do it that way. Plus czech really looks terrible in code...

Comment: I wonder what identifiers in czech with hungarian notation would look like :-) SCNR.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong size is passed to malloc function:  `sizeof(char)` **that should be** `sizeof(char*)`:

```
pole = (char **)malloc(pocet * sizeof(*char));
```

`sizeof(char) != sizeof(char*)` and also don't use type cast for malloc().

And similar error I can see in your code in `realloc`  :

error at:  `pole = (char **)realloc(pole, pocet * sizeof(char));`

also a syntax error, `;` is missing :

char texttex

Comment: So here is my fixed code but still it doesn't work.



int row = 5;
int column = 5;
int countr = 0;
int countr2 = 0;

int c;
int **array;

 array = (int **)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
 for(i=0; i<row; i++){
      pole[i] = (int*)malloc(column * sizeof(int*));    
 }

 while(read letters(300row) form file (c=fgetc()) != EOF{

  if(coutr>=(size-1)){
   row+=10;
         array = (int **)realloc(array, row * sizeof(int*));
  }

  array[countr][countr2] = c;
  countr2++;
  if(c == '\0' || c == ' '){
   countr2=0;
   countr++;
  }
 }


and pls can you explain me what does it man "type cast"

Comment: @user13746 : write this code in your question: after EDIT:, I can't understand this in comment

Comment: I mean by `"typecast" is that you can simple write  `pole = malloc(pocet * sizeof(*char));` here no need to typecast by `(char**)` or (char*).

Answer (score 2):

This code is so broken as to be impossible to diagnose what's wrong. As an example,

```
int tex = 255;

char texttex 
for(i= 0; tex ;i++){
     text[i]='\0';     
}
```

is missing a semicolon after `char texttex` and is an infinite loop since `tex` is always 255. Please provide a **complete minimal compilable code**. If you expect others to spend time for you, you should start by spending some of your time for us. Thank you.

Comment: Sry for these type mistakes, but these for only  because of fast writing, so Now it's ok

Comment: Never type! Better to use cut and paste to avoid silly typos.